# React Native inserting data to a nested array

Tags: react-native

I want to add data to the "key" in "title" and "data" in the menu array. I add the title in the menu array like this in the code below. How can I add data to the key in the data array?

```
 constructor(props) {
  menu :[
        { 
          title: '', 
          data: [
            {key:'', value:''},
          
          ] 
        }]  }


   _getDATA = async () => {
    try {
      let rsp = await getSSS()
      rsp = await rsp.json()
this.setState({
        SSS: rsp.cikti
      }, () => {
this.state.SSS.map((item, index) => {
this.setState(prevState => ({
  menu: [...prevState.menu, {"title": item.SSS_Title}]
}))          

                    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(props) {
  menu :[
        { 
          title: '', 
          data: [
            {key:'', value:''},
          
          ] 
        }]  }


   _getDATA = async () => {
    try {
      let rsp = await getSSS()
      rsp = await rsp.json()
this.setState({
        SSS: rsp.cikti
      }, () => {
this.state.SSS.map((item, index) => {
this.setState(prevState => ({
  menu: [...prevState.menu, {"title": item.SSS_Title, data: [...item.SSS_data]}]
}))          

                    })
```

Comment: There is a key in the data array, so I will pass that data to data [key: '', value: false] key, not data

Comment: you should put what item looks like and what u expect with a more clearly way I don't get what you is your expected result